# Database in Android phone?

Tags: android, database

I am working on android database retrieval  application.  So far my application is working well in my emulator.  But its not working in my phone.  I have stored my database in the internal memory of emulator.  Where shall I put the database in phone?

Comment: user1186739 how you placed your database in internal memory of emulator , if you have just placed the database in the internal memory of emulator by pushing it into the memory by ddms view, it shall not work on the device

Answer (score 2):

the same code will work on the phone also, but you cannot view the database on phone

you can view only if the phone is rooted or else it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can create databases as in your phone..

```
       dbPath = "/data/data/"+context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/databases/"+databasename.db;
 SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

you can find this database from terminal using this command

```
./adb shell
cd data/data
cd packagename

sqlite3 databasename.db
```

you can put zroot file without this file you can not access this databases.
see this link

```
http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/z4root-is-one-click-root-app-for-samsung-galaxy-s-android-phones/
```

Comment: In emulator i have pushed  my database data/data/cis493.sqldatabases/databases folde as          db= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
         "/data/data/cis493.sqldatabases/databases/multilinguialdatabase.sqlite", null,
         SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY); but in when i transfer .apk file to phone its not retrieving.I have no idea where to put the database

Comment: that is because you have not send data base to your device.check the link

Comment: if you dont have root access for the phone then it can not be retrived.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using External data base you have to write code which will copy data base to your application folder. Following is really good tutorial which you should read and implement with your code
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ .